# useradd encrypting password

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating script that would automatise creating user. I used `useradd $username -p $password -g $group`, that worked but when trying to login the password is always wrong. I had found on Internet that it is because the password as argument need to be crypted, but I couldn't find anything that would help me to create crypted password. The only thing that I found is `openssl passwd -crypt $password` but I can't use redirection to this command and I don't know how to send output of this to variable (`$rpassword`). My question is how create encrypted password that I can store in variable so I can use it in `adduser -p $rpassword`. If this may help the target computer is Raspberry Pi that using os NOOBS.

Comment: Another thing that would help would be the operating system that you're running on the Raspberry Pi.  I run FreeBSD on mine.  What are you using?

Comment: I'm using NOOBS on Raspberry Pi

Comment: NOOBS lets you install any of a number of operating systems - Debian, OpenELEC, Pidora, Arch, RISCOS, etc.  It doesn't matter whether your installer came from NOOBS or a USB stick or a CD-ROM, it's the operating system you installed that affects what tools are available.

Comment: I don't know then someone else was installing the os and I don't have access to Pi right now. I had checked on googles versions that you had written but I don't think its any of them

Comment: The list of operating systems you can install using NOOBS is included in [the NOOBS documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md). Once you have access to the device, there are a number of ways you can determine what operating system you are running, though the process in Linux is too long for a comment like this. I'm sure Google can help you in this too.

Answer (score 1):

in bash you can do

```
encpass=$(openssl passwd -crypt abc123)
```

to define your variable alternatively create the user without password and then use passwd to set it

checkout the man pages for --stdin option